# Why this python program is not working? AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, random

I wrote a very simple python program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
x = random.uniform(-1, 1)
print str(x)
```

I run this from command prompt.

```
python random.py
```

It returned with error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 2, in <module>
    import random
  File "D:\python practise\random.py", line 3, in <module>
    x = random.uniform(-1, 1)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uniform'
```

It is a very simple program, I can't understand what mistake I did in this.

(operating system: Windows 7; python version: 2.7)

Comment: 3 votes seriously?

Comment: On windows the shebang syntax `#!usr/bin/env python` is not necessary; it does absolutely nothing. That's for Unix-like OSes so that the shell can know how to run the script

Comment: @Rafe it also doesn't hurt and why assume it'll always run in a non-Unixy environment?

Comment: @Daniel it isn't necessary on Unix either. I just don't want OP to go through their entire life not getting why that's there

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Don't name your file `random.py`, it is importing itself and looking for `uniform` in it.

It's a bit of a quirk with how Python imports things, it looks in the local directory first and then starts searching the `PYTHONPATH`.  Basically, be careful naming any of your `.py` files the same as one of the standard library modules.

Answer (score 4):

Don't name your program as an Library.
And just as a Tip: You don't need an String storing something and printing it out just after generating it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
print(random.uniform(-1, 1))
```

This will work fine too ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you named your test program "random.py".  The current working directory is on the module search path before anything else, so when you say "import random", it imports *your own test program* rather than the standard library random.

Rename your test program -- or just take the `.py` suffix off -- and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is renaming your file `(random.py)` to something other than Python built-ins, standard libraries, reserved keywords etc.

However I strongly recommend you take [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html), before trying any other tutorial or book. You especially need to learn more about [Python scopes and namespaces](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).