# Python 'function' object has no attribute 'uniform'

Tags: python

I'm extremely new to Python (as in this is the first script I've written), and I'm just messing around trying to make something that will work.

I've written the following:

```
# Roll the Dice

from random import randint

x = randint.uniform(1, 6)
y = randint.uniform(1, 6)

print str(x + y)
```

This should simply return any integer between 2 and 12, but I'm getting the following error message when I try to run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/FilePath/Python Testing.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = randint.uniform(1, 6)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'uniform'
```

I feel like this is a super easy script and shouldn't be failing, but since I'm so new to this I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting.  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761138/why-this-python-program-is-not-working) SO question that is similar, but the resolution does not fit my problem (or so I think).

I'm using Python 2.7.12 via PyCharm 2016.1.4

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's `random.uniform`, not `randint.uniform`. You'll have to change your import to `import random`, or `from random import uniform` and then you can use the unqualified name.

Comment: yep...figured it was something stupid like that...thank you very much

Comment: You don't want `uniform` to simulate dice rolls, since it returns floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up modules and functions.  randint is a fuction in the random module, as is uniform.  Instead of loading just the randint function, load the whole module.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html for more information

```
# Roll the Dice

import random

x = random.randint(1, 6)
y = random.randint(1, 6)

print str(x + y)

x = random.uniform(1, 6)
y = random.uniform(1, 6)

print str(x + y)
```

Answer (score 1):

`uniform` and `randint` are both functions* defined in the `random` module.

```
from random import uniform
x = uniform(1, 6)
```

---

* Not quite; there is a module-level global RNG whose methods are accessible as module-level names.